# How to restore large Tensorforce agent (18GB) after training

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I have tried to train a PPOAgent with `Tensorforce` library with a data set around 100 variable.

However, after training and saved the agent, I am not able to restore the agent for further training and the system gave me below error.

```
{2019-03-16 13:30:04.301893: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:184 : Out of range: Read fewer bytes than requested}
```

I also tried to train and restore smaller agent (<1GB) and succeed, therefore I think that it is not because of coding error.

My system should be fully capable to run the model and it is only trained with CPU. This is the spec as shown below:

```
Google VM 8 CPU 2GHz
512 GB RAM and hard disk
Windows Server 2016
Tensorflow 1.13.1
Tensorforce 0.4.3
Anaconda Python 3.6.8
```

It will be great if anyone can share ideas to solve this problem and will be highly appreciated.

> My code is as shown below:

```
def create_network_spec():
network_spec = [
    {"type": "flatten"},
    dict(size= 152, type = 'dense', activation = 'selu', l2_regularization = 0.007920429669304596, 
         l1_regularization = 0.07371959121453227),
    dict(type = 'dropout', rate = 0.12911336420147002),
    dict(size= 228, type = 'dense', activation = 'selu', l2_regularization = 0.007920429669304596, 
         l1_regularization = 0.07371959121453227),
    dict(type = 'dropout', rate = 0.12911336420147002),
    dict(type='internal_lstm', size=456, dropout = 0.12911336420147002),
    dict(type='internal_lstm', size=456, dropout = 0.12911336420147002),
    dict(type='internal_lstm', size=456, dropout = 0.12911336420147002),
]
return network_spec

def create_baseline_spec():
baseline_spec = [
    {
        "type": "lstm",
        "size": 456,
    },
    dict(type='dense', size=228, activation='selu'),
    dict(type = 'dropout', rate = 0.12911336420147002),
    dict(type='dense', size=152, activation='selu'),
    dict(type = 'dropout', rate = 0.12911336420147002),
    dict(type='dense', size=114, activation='selu'),
    dict(type = 'dropout', rate = 0.12911336420147002),
]
return baseline_spec

def testing_agent(environment):

network_spec = create_network_spec()
baseline_spec = create_baseline_spec()
agent = PPOAgent(
    discount=0.9677484438906688,
    states=environment.states,
    actions=environment.actions,
    network=network_spec,
    states_preprocessing=None,
    actions_exploration=None,
    reward_preprocessing=None,
    update_mode=dict(
        unit= 'episodes',
        batch_size= 800,
        frequency=12
    ),
    memory=None, 
    distributions=None,
    entropy_regularization=0.8766700482699176,

    baseline_mode='states',
    baseline=dict(type='custom', network=baseline_spec),
    baseline_optimizer=dict(
        type='multi_step',
        optimizer=dict(
            type='adam',
            learning_rate=0.7342086295731822
        ),
        num_steps=17
    ),
    gae_lambda=0.9285969986276199,
    likelihood_ratio_clipping=0.9837192515975488,
    step_optimizer=dict(
        type='adam',
        learning_rate=0.7342086295731822
    ),
    subsampling_fraction=0.1,
    optimization_steps=17,
    execution=None
)
try :
    agent.restore_model("./model_new/")
except:
    agent.save_model("./model_new/")
return agent
```